# Типы: varchar и text в Postgresql

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

В документации увидел тип `varchar`, а в книжке которой сейчас читаю тип `text` в первых же примерах. Почитал на разных ресурсах получается только в длине символов отличие или еще в чём-то? Какой вы бы советовали использовать и почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В текущих версия СУБД технической разницы между ними нет, хранятся они одинаково. Но я бы рекомендовал всегда формировать как можно более строгую схему, используя `varchar`, когда известна максимальная длина хранимой строки, а `text` в тех случаях, когда неизвестна.

Comment: Спасибо большое!